# Mac OSX Keychain Certificates Force Delete ? Expired Cerficates

Tags: macos, terminal, certificate, keychain

**How do you force delete via terminal or keychain access an expired certificate on a Mac OSX environment?**

I have followed instructions to use these commands:

```
$sudo /usr/bin/security  find-certificate -a -Z -c "Ricardo" |grep SHA-1
```

> SHA-1 hash: E255796FF19E4BB84C576BF9DF7CDD6D85E5E3E3 
>   SHA-1 hash: EA874FE7A139F7209BE90DDEF52988C5CE046097
>   SHA-1 hash: 17115A26F95F98B70493015F1BCAFB23AAB051CB
>
> $sudo security delete-certificate -Z 17115A26F95F98B70493015F1BCAFB23AAB051CB /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
>
> Unable to delete certificate matching "17115A26F95F98B70493015F1BCAFB23AAB051CB"l-0268:~ ricardo$
>
> tried using -c as well:
>   `$sudo security delete-certificate -c -f "Ricardo"/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain`
>
> Unable to delete certificate matching
>   "17115A26F95F98B70493015F1BCAFB23AAB051CB"

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to delete these certificates in the Keychain Access?

Comment: That's the problem Hamid, the Keychain Access system does not delete them using the GUI.